# Не генерируются json файлы для Allure отчета при запуске ui автотестов

Tags: python, selenium, allure

При выполнение команды "pytest --alluredir results" в терминале pycharm'а генерируется папка results, однако консоль пишет "collected 0 items" и в папке json-ы не генерятся, насколько я понимаю тесты по сути не запускаются и соответственно результатов никаких нет, почему так происходит? Кажется, что есть какая-то очевидная проблема, но как часто бывает невидимая для ищущего)

Выглядит все это следующим образом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В "test_login" имею следующий код:

```
@allure.feature('Smoke tests')
@allure.story('Вход')
def test_login(login, password):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get('path_to_web')
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.maximize_window()
    ...
    assert True
```

При запуске main.py все отрабатывает корректно, страница открывается и логиниться

Заранее благодарю всех за ответы!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пофиксилось запуском теста с помощью команды:
`python -m pytest path\main.py --alluredir results`

Далее отчет генерируется стандартной командой:
`allure serve path\results`